# permission denied for schema api in tutorial

Tags: postgresql, postgrest

I'm trying a new thing, but I get stuck on the tutorial. When I follow step 4 of this tutorial:

https://postgrest.org/en/v9.0/tutorials/tut0.html#step-4-create-database-for-api

the SQL just runs without error. I can see the table+data.

However, when I log in as the newly created user `authenticator`, and try `select * from api.todos;`, I get the error:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for schema api
LINE 1: select * from api.todos;
```

I tried it on Postgres 13+14 on my [Postgres.app](https://postgresapp.com), and also on Postgres 13.4 on Debian. Same error.

Any help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's intended. `authenticator` doesn't have any privilege but to switch roles, as mentioned on https://postgrest.org/en/v9.0/auth.html#authentication-sequence.

So after connecting with `authenticator` through `psql`, you can do:

```
set local role web_anon;
```

Then you should be able to `select * from api.todos`.

Comment: Ah, this was not obvious. I learned something new. Thanks!